# Bootstrap Collapse Plugin not collapsing

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, plugins

I´m working on a responsive website where I´m using a little trick which I´ve used on a different site before, but it´s not working on the newer one.

Old Site: http://1098756.webtonia.com/
New Site: http://11043044.webtonia.com/

Edit: View the Sites with a small browser-viewport.

It´s basically exactly the same. I´m using Bootstrap with the collapse plugin, but on the newer site, the bootstrap collapse plugin doesn´t seem to work properly. It gets the class "collapse in" once I click the toggle button, but after that it doesn´t go back up.

I´ve tried using the exact code (since it´s not 100% the same, but that´s just HTML and not such a big difference that it should affect the bs-plugin). I also tried calling the plugin manually which also didn´t work. Since I´m not that good of a coder I´m at a point where I tried everything I know.

Thanks in advance, I hope this isn´t just a stupid mistake :D

Edit2: I just realized that some scripts (jquery and bootstrap) are implemented two times, I´ll see if that was the error

Comment: Please include code examples in your question for further readers.

Comment: What kind of exmaples would you like to see? Because everything you need would be on the two pages, and since I don´t know where the problem lies, I wouldn´t know what kind of code people would find useful, sorry :/

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your edit. Does removing the duplicate files help?

Comment: See my comment to @HTTPs answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just included 2 times the bootstrap css file. Remove the other one and I think also the bootstrap js file. See image and scroll down a little bit in rendered css. Notice the `display: block` rendered in class `in`.

Hope it helps :)[image]

Comment: Okay the problem is I´m not entirely sure where it comes from, I guess it comes from the wp_header(); part, but I can´t alter what that puts out (can I). Deleting my implemented stuff doesn´t work either, maybe I should put all the code in a js file and include it in the head?

Comment: Removing the duplicate scripts does help the bootstrap function, but now my stuff isn´t working anymore. I´ll get to the bottom of this. thanks for your help!

Comment: The files initially came from bootstrap shortcodes plugin which includes all of the files (which I didn´t know).